# root (cern) crashes with a libpng issue Fedora 20

Tags: crash, libpng, root-framework

I installed the last version of root from source, downloaded from cern website, and I am not able to open the TBrowser, due to the error I attach at the end of the message. I have already searched for help on several question on the root forum, but didn't find anything that worked for me or that helped me. Could anyone help me debugging this issue? thanks for any reply

```
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.6
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image
Warning in <TASImage::GetMask>: No image

 *** Break *** segmentation violation



===========================================================
There was a crash.
This is the entire stack trace of all threads:
===========================================================
#0  0x00007fc03ffe13ac in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fc03ff675b2 in do_system () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fc040c92ec9 in TUnixSystem::StackTrace() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#3  0x00007fc040c94aec in TUnixSystem::DispatchSignals(ESignals) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x00007fc039960971 in asimage_init () from /usr/local/lib/root/libASImage.so
#6  0x00007fc039961242 in destroy_asimage () from /usr/local/lib/root/libASImage.so
#7  0x00007fc03999ebb4 in merge_layers () from /usr/local/lib/root/libASImage.so
#8  0x00007fc039943da6 in TASImage::Merge(TImage const*, char const*, int, int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libASImage.so
#9  0x00007fc03b1dc35c in TGPictureButton::CreateDisabledPicture() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#10 0x00007fc03b1d908c in TGPictureButton::DoRedraw() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#11 0x00007fc03b1d68fc in TGButton::SetState(EButtonState, bool) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#12 0x00007fc03b28b064 in TGTextEditor::Build() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#13 0x00007fc03b28c345 in TGTextEditor::TGTextEditor(char const*, TGWindow const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#14 0x00007fc03b548c73 in G__G__Gui3_385_0_2(G__value*, char const*, G__param*, int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#15 0x00007fc03f44137d in Cint::G__ExceptionWrapper(int (*)(G__value*, char const*, G__param*, int), G__value*, char*, G__param*, int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#16 0x00007fc03f48c307 in G__execute_call () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#17 0x00007fc03f48c6c5 in G__call_cppfunc () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#18 0x00007fc03f40a16d in G__interpret_func () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#19 0x00007fc03f51d867 in G__getfunction () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#20 0x00007fc03f44412c in G__new_operator () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#21 0x00007fc03f41d72d in G__exec_statement () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#22 0x00007fc03f3e6dd6 in G__exec_tempfile_core () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#23 0x00007fc03f3e82be in G__exec_tempfile_fp () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#24 0x00007fc03f537c69 in G__process_cmd () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#25 0x00007fc040c62120 in TCint::ProcessLine(char const*, TInterpreter::EErrorCode*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#26 0x00007fc040c030ab in TApplication::ProcessLine(char const*, bool, int*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#27 0x00007fc040c28bdc in TROOT::ProcessLine(char const*, int*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#28 0x00007fc03b24d741 in TRootBrowser::ExecPlugin(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#29 0x00007fc03b24e4f8 in TRootBrowser::InitPlugins(char const*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#30 0x00007fc03b24e938 in TRootBrowser::TRootBrowser(TBrowser*, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, bool) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#31 0x00007fc03b24ee38 in TRootBrowser::NewBrowser(TBrowser*, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#32 0x00007fc03b56af8a in G__G__Gui3_418_0_47(G__value*, char const*, G__param*, int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#33 0x00007fc03f44063b in Cint::G__CallFunc::Execute(void*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#34 0x00007fc040c5d3e1 in TCint::CallFunc_ExecInt(void*, void*) const () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#35 0x00007fc040c59861 in TMethodCall::Execute(void*, long&) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#36 0x00007fc040c2cce2 in TPluginHandler::ExecPlugin(int, ...) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#37 0x00007fc03b26c7b9 in TRootGuiFactory::CreateBrowserImp(TBrowser*, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#38 0x00007fc040c0af0a in TBrowser::TBrowser(char const*, char const*, TBrowserImp*, char const*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#39 0x00007fc040cf00e0 in G__G__Base1_85_0_3(G__value*, char const*, G__param*, int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#40 0x00007fc03f44137d in Cint::G__ExceptionWrapper(int (*)(G__value*, char const*, G__param*, int), G__value*, char*, G__param*, int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#41 0x00007fc03f48c307 in G__execute_call () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#42 0x00007fc03f48c6c5 in G__call_cppfunc () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#43 0x00007fc03f40a16d in G__interpret_func () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#44 0x00007fc03f51d867 in G__getfunction () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#45 0x00007fc03f4d4ee9 in G__define_var () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#46 0x00007fc03f41891c in G__exec_statement () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#47 0x00007fc03f3e6dd6 in G__exec_tempfile_core () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#48 0x00007fc03f3e82be in G__exec_tempfile_fp () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#49 0x00007fc03f537c69 in G__process_cmd () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCint.so
#50 0x00007fc040c62120 in TCint::ProcessLine(char const*, TInterpreter::EErrorCode*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#51 0x00007fc040c030ab in TApplication::ProcessLine(char const*, bool, int*) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#52 0x00007fc04081faa9 in TRint::HandleTermInput() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libRint.so
#53 0x00007fc040c942b5 in TUnixSystem::CheckDescriptors() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#54 0x00007fc040c94dda in TUnixSystem::DispatchOneEvent(bool) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#55 0x00007fc040bf2956 in TSystem::InnerLoop() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#56 0x00007fc040bf3500 in TSystem::Run() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#57 0x00007fc040c0173f in TApplication::Run(bool) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#58 0x00007fc040820bc7 in TRint::Run(bool) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libRint.so
#59 0x0000000000400fec in main ()
===========================================================


The lines below might hint at the cause of the crash.
If they do not help you then please submit a bug report at
http://root.cern.ch/bugs. Please post the ENTIRE stack trace
from above as an attachment in addition to anything else
that might help us fixing this issue.
===========================================================
#5  0x00007fc039960971 in asimage_init () from /usr/local/lib/root/libASImage.so
#6  0x00007fc039961242 in destroy_asimage () from /usr/local/lib/root/libASImage.so
#7  0x00007fc03999ebb4 in merge_layers () from /usr/local/lib/root/libASImage.so
#8  0x00007fc039943da6 in TASImage::Merge(TImage const*, char const*, int, int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libASImage.so
#9  0x00007fc03b1dc35c in TGPictureButton::CreateDisabledPicture() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#10 0x00007fc03b1d908c in TGPictureButton::DoRedraw() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#11 0x00007fc03b1d68fc in TGButton::SetState(EButtonState, bool) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#12 0x00007fc03b28b064 in TGTextEditor::Build() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
#13 0x00007fc03b28c345 in TGTextEditor::TGTextEditor(char const*, TGWindow const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libGui.so
===========================================================
```

Comment: Have you tried re-linking your TSAImage application after you upgraded libpng?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could yuo kindly explain me how to re-link my TASImage to the right libpng?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem, on Ubuntu.  There, "new TBrowser" failed with unable to find libpng.16.so.16.  Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the directory containing libpng.16.so seems to fix the problem (on Ubuntu I also needed it to point to the library containing root's libCore.so), so my command is LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/root/lib/root:$HOME/lib export LD_LIBRARY_PATH where libCore.so is in the first directory and libpng16 is in the second. I did not have to do any relinking.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your environment, to point to the directory that contains libpng16 (for example, if libpng16.so is in /path/to/lib/libpng16.so, do this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ root
root[0] new TBrowser
```

That worked for me on Ubuntu, although I also had to include the path to libCore.so that is installed along with root.

Comment: running `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0.50.0 root` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you build root (assuming you're installing from source), try running configure with the `--disable-builtin-afterimage` option.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that option doesn't help.